# Why doesn't Resharper offer "Create nested class" and other context actions sometimes?

Tags: c#, resharper

Using Resharper 5 and Visual Studio 2010, C#.

The class StackOverflow in the following code doesn't yet exist, and yet Resharper doesn't offer context options like "Create nested class" for it. Could you explain why?

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class SomeSetOfTests
    {
        public void AFirstTest()
        {
            var overflow = new StackOverflow();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: [In truth I have the answer, but couldn't find it on the web so thought I'd archive it here -- am happy to accept someone else's answer]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're in a namespace called `StackOverflow`. That's bound to cause problems. I mean, you *could* create a class with the same name - the following compiles:

```
namespace StackOverflow
{
    public class SomeSetOfTests
    {
        public void AFirstTest()
        {
            var overflow = new StackOverflow();
        }

        private class StackOverflow
        {
        }
    }
}
```

... but it's a [really bad idea](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/tags/namespaces/).

I would guess that ReSharper is trying to save you from your folly.

Comment: Heh, indeed, it's tempting fate even for sample code :) But yes, classname = namespace, er, name is the key.

Comment: It is, although I figured it just got confused because a symbol StackOverflow already existed rather than it being deliberate. In any case: agreed, and clearly no right thinking dev would consider doing this, even in some example code *cough*.